# Cucumber - caching step_definition.rb files?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber

It looks like cucumber is caching .rb files between runs. I'm making updates to my step definitions, but I'm not seeing any changes in test behavior. Is there any way to stop cucumber from caching?

Comment: I run cucumber without a rake task - just via the gem. I'm outside the context of a rails project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer, and this seemed to work. Very scientific.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the workspace after every build, you can configure this for every job you have in Jenkins, this will remove your problem. This, of course, if you are using Jenkins.